# How to switch text boxes focus when third digit was reached?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I am using 2 text boxes which will input int digits to max length of 3. How can I pass a mouse pointer from first text box to the second one when 3 digits were entered?

I am trying to do it on TextChange event, but I'm not sure how to check when 3rd digit was checked...

```
public partial class PingIPRange : Form
{
    public PingIPRange()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        txtF1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(NextField);
        txtF2.TextChanged += new EventHandler(NextField);
    }

    private void NextField(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Well, I have no idea how to start with this...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mythje, OP is using WinForms..

Comment: @Shai wops my bad i guess it's still early ><'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once `txtF1.Text.Length == 3`, you can use `txtF2.Focus()` in order to 'move the cursor' to the 2nd textbox

EDIT:

```
private void NextField(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtF1.Text.Length == 3) // Textbox contains 3 characters, you DO NEED to validate your input.
        txtF2.Focus();
}
```

Comment: +1 - looks like we were typing at the same time. Beat me to it.

Comment: `if (txtF1.TextLength == 3) txtF2.Focus();`

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you want the mouse pointer to move rather than the "carot" for typing, which is standard practice.

You'll want to check the string length within the text box as each character is entered and then set the Focus to the new text box.

Comment: I did mean to switch the 'caror' character, yet.

Answer (score 0):

Like in the previous answers, you probably want `TextBox.Focus()`, but in case you actually wanted to move the pointer:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Length == 3) { Cursor.Position = textBox2.Location; }
    }
```

Comment: When control is in focus, it means it's capturing the keystrokes. if you set .Focus() on your control, when you press the key, the control will take it. My example shows hot to physically move mouse arrow to desired location but not more than this, so if you did that your textbox1 would still be the one accepting keystrokes.